# i am writing a small interpreter in c++, but it returns me an error "vector subscript out of range"

Tags: c++, vector, interpreter

I am writing a very simple interpreter with these two commands: "print:value", to print and "printnl:value", to print in a new line and i use vectors to store the command and the value.
the problem is that when i input something it returns ma an error "vector subscript out of range" and some random exit code.
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<string> brk_token(string text, char breakon) {
    vector<string> tokens;
    string token = "";
    for (int i = 0;i < text.size(); i++) {
        if (text.at(i) != breakon) {
            token += text.at(i);
        }
        else {
            tokens.push_back(token);
            token = "";
        }


    }
    return tokens;
}

int main() {

    string program;
    while (true) {
        getline(cin, program);
        if (brk_token(program.c_str(), ':')[0] == "print") {
            cout << brk_token(program.c_str(), ':')[1];
        }
        else if (brk_token(program.c_str(), ':')[0] == "printnl") {
            cout << brk_token(program.c_str(), ':')[1] << "\n";
        }
        if (program == "break") {
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I wrote: "print:hello" and "printnl:hello" and every time it returned that error, i wrote some random characters and the result is the same, can someone help?

Comment: *I am writing a very simple interpreter with these two commands: "print:value"* -- Replace `getline(cin, program);` with `program = "print:value";`.  That way, others can simply run your code without having to type in the data every time.

Comment: That means you are out of bounds.

Comment: `brk_token(program.c_str(), ':')[0]` -- What if `brk_token` returns an empty vector?  There is no `[0]` element.  Also, [what is a debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Your current if () assume the vector has at least 2 elements. Instead of assuming that you should check first.

Comment: `program.c_str()` is not good code. Just use `program` the function expects a string

Comment: the exit code is not random. Its a common mistake of beginners to call things the do not understand "random". The exit code can hold useful information on the cause of a crash

Comment: it returns an error when gets to the `brk_token(program.c_str(), ':')[1];`

Comment: @AndreiBruma think real hard about what could possibly cause that line to fail with a bounds error. There is only 1 bound being accessed - `[1]`. So, the error means that index 1 is not valid in the vector, which means the vector does not have at least 2 elements in it, which means `brk_token()` is not returning what you are expecting. So go debug that function to see what it is really returning and why.

Comment: That is because `brk_token(program.c_str(), ':')` didn't return a vector containing 2 elements.

Comment: Side note: the loop `for (int i = 0;i < text.size(); i++)` ensures that `i` is a valid index into `text`. There's no need to test it twice more with `text.at(i)`; just use `text[i]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of `brk_token()`, when the loop reaches the end of the string, you are not pushing the final `token` into the `vector`. As such, inside of `main()`, you have *undefined behavior* when you try to access the `vector[1]` element that doesn't exist.

Also, some other issues with your code:

- the `string::at()` method performs bounds checking at runtime, but you are doing your own bounds checking in the `for` loop that iterates through a `string`, so using `at()` is useless overhead. You can safely use `string::operator[]` instead.
- your `while` loop in `main()` is not checking whether `getline()` is successful or not before processing the `string`.
- when calling `brk_token()`, you are converting the `string` into a `const char*` just to convert it back to a `string` again. You don't need to use `string::c_str()` in this code at all.
- calling `brk_token()` repeatedly is overkill. Call it one time per `string` and save the result into a local variable that you can then validate before using.

With all of that said, try this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<string> brk_token(const string &text, char breakon) {
    vector<string> tokens;
    string token;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < text.size(); ++i) {
        if (text[i] != breakon) {
            token += text[i];
        }
        else {
            tokens.push_back(token);
            token = "";
        }
    }

    if (!token.empty())
        tokens.push_back(token);

    return tokens;
}

int main() {

    string program;
    vector<string> tokens;

    while (getline(cin, program) && (program != "break")) {
        tokens = brk_token(program, ':');
        if (tokens.size() != 2) {
            cerr << "Bad input\n";
        }
        else if (tokens[0] == "print") {
            cout << tokens[1];
        }
        else if (tokens[0] == "printnl") {
            cout << tokens[1] << '\n';
        }
        else {
            cerr << "Unknown input\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```